# Java 8u74 classLoader.getResource("").getPath(); returns NULL

Tags: java, java-web-start

We are using Java web start for deploying our application.
All JAR files are signed and there is no problem with deploying and using the application with all Java versions (including 8u73).

With JRE 8u74, application was deployed OK (all JAR files downloaded and application started correctly).
When trying to extract a file from a JAR file we are getting the following message:

```
Failed to validate certificate. The application will not be executed.

java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not verify signing in resource: https://www.example.com:443/app/myFile.jar
            at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.ensureAllJarEntriesSigned(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.getValidationState(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGrantedInt(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassLoader.getResourcePermission(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source)
            at com.til.manager.B.A.A(Unknown Source)
            at com.til.manager.B.A.D(Unknown Source)
            at com.til.manager.B.A.B(Unknown Source)
            at com.til.manager.app.H$6.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Could not verify signing in resource: https://www.example.com:443/app/myFile.jar
```

This happens for several files.
This error message is shown when our application tries to extract files from the JAR files to the local computer.

Further investigating we found that on 8u74, for the following code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
classLoader.getResource("").getPath();
```

the second line returns `NULL`.
On all previous Java version this was working correctly.

Could this be connected to the error message?

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix this problem?

Comment: What do you think `classLoader.getResource("")` is supposed to return? Do you have a resource called `EMPTY_STRING` in the same folder as the `class`? Otherwise, returning `null` is the behaviour specified in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).

Comment: What do you mean by "working correctly"? How is the result of `classLoader.getResource("")` defined?

Comment: I wonder if OP confuses the behaviour of `classLoader.getResource("")` with `new File("")`.

Comment: @Tom there is an UB for `URLClassLoader` that _does_ return the path for  `getResource` on a folder. I reckon the OP is relying on that for some logic...

Answer (score 0):

[The API documentation for `ClassLoader.getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) claims that it will return null "if the resource could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource". Moreover, I tested the code you listed using the OpenJDK 1.7.0_95 as well as the Oracle JDK 1.8.0_72, and with both of them it did *not* return null on my system but rather it returned the execution directory (e.g. `/home/errantlinguist/Eclipse%20Workspaces/Default/ClassLoaderTest8/bin/`).

These two pieces of evidence suggest that the null reference you're getting is a symptom of the problem rather than the cause: [`CertificateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateException.html) "indicates one of a variety of certificate problems", and is moreover a subclass of [`GeneralSecurityException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/GeneralSecurityException.html)-- note the words *privileges* and *security*.

Are you absolutely sure that your manifest for `myFile.jar` is correct?-- If so, what exact JVM are you runnng?-- If your manifest is correct, it is possible this problem may be related to [a reported bug in OpenJDK 8u72](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8147920). Unfortunately, without further information about your deployment, it isn't possible to know for sure.

Comment: Manifest file is:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Permissions: all-permissions
Created-By: 1.6.0_31 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
 
Name: myFile/file.txt
SHA1-Digest: ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the Jar referred to by my JNLP had only DLLs in it, no Java code. Upon reading hundreds of similar threads relating to this problem it became apparent that I might need to add a Jar to the JNLP that actually included Java code.  So, my original JNLP included 4 Jars with DLLs as follows:

```
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <nativelib href="lib/jogl/jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <nativelib href="lib/jogl/jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
    <nativelib href="lib/jogl/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <resources os="Windows" arch="amd64">
    <nativelib href="lib/jogl/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar"/>
  </resources>
```

This failed with the Java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not verify signing in resource: ...

Then, when I added a signed Jar that has Java code in it as follows, the problem went away:

```
  <resources>
    <jar href="lib/hdf/jhdf.jar"/>
  </resources>
```

Comment: You can use jogamp-fat.jar to avoid having to manage the JARs containing the native libraries and it would solve your problem as it contains Java code too, it's just a lot bigger as it contains GlueGen, JOGL, JOAL and JOCL.